# Avoid UITableViewCell moving when toggling between editing mode

Tags: iphone, objective-c, cocoa-touch, ipad, uikit

Alright, I have some weird behavior and this question goes to the people out there that got that issue already.

I have 4 different subclasses of UITableViewCells. They are all very similar (I can't see the differences that would bring the problem up).

Now my UITableView's delegate have the following code:

```
- (UITableViewCellEditingStyle)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView editingStyleForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
{
    if (indexPath.section < 2)
             return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
     else if (indexPath.row == [[AccountManager sharedManager].accounts count])
      return UITableViewCellEditingStyleNone;
     else return UITableViewCellEditingStyleDelete;
 }
```

Now, what I'd expect would be to have the first 2 rows not changing upon changing the state of setEditing: property of my tableView.

Here's the tricky part:

the first 2 rows they move right without having the "delete icon" appearing.

In the last **section**, the cells don't move a single pixel to the right and only the rows are having the "delete icon" appearing.

Here's some info:

None of my cellviews and subviews implement - (void)layoutSubviews

All of them implement - (void)drawRect:(CGRect)rect

All the cell and cell's subviews ContentMode are set to their default settings
All the autoresizingMask are set to their default settings.

Any idea?

Comment: Nevermind I'm an idiot. I was adding my subviews to UITableViewCell's view instead of cell.contentView I'll keep it here in case someone gets this error

Comment: You may want to post this as an "answer" so people know this is closed and you get reputation points for selecting it as the correct answer.

Comment: I agree, I'll do it right away

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you add your subview directly to the UITableViewCell, the animation won't work when toggling the editing mode in the UITableView.

If you want them to be activated, you should add your subview to UITableViewCell's contentView property.

Comment: just changed my custom tableview cell from [self addSubview:view] to [self contentView] addSubview:view] and it worked ! Cheers